# how to get out of the fancybox iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I have to do some form submission and then get out of the fancybox which holds an iframe. How to do that? I tried using `$.fn.fancybox.close();` but it cause some error.

Answer (score 1):

Remember the [Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)

If your iframe is from another domain you can't have js communication with your site

Answer (score 1):

I use this script to close a Fancybox iframe after submission:

```
parent.$.fn.fancybox.close();
```

Comment: where exactly do you put this? i tried it in the `head` of my iframe page, also after `$.fancybox({ ... });` -- but it doesn't work -- my iframe is within my domain

Comment: It's in the iframed document, and should work as long as it comes after the inclusion of jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

use this simply

```
$.fancybox.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

If your iframe is on the same domain try using `parent.fancybox_instance.close()` inside the iframe